# restart (or reload the config of) Eclipse-CS programmatically

Tags: eclipse, checkstyle

I am trying to reconfigure the CheckStyle plugin for Eclipse (Eclipse-CS) from code (while Eclipse is running). So far the only way I have found to do this is by replacing the XML file with the config and reloading the config manually.

Replacing the XML file is not the elegant solution I was hoping for but it works; however I still need a way to make Eclipse-CS actually load the config file.

I have been searching for a way to achieve this but I am out of ideas.

Comment: Note to Googlers: the accepted answer says there is no way to do it *programmatically*, but if you want to refresh the plugin *in Eclipse*, read on to Christian's answer with six times the upvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been struggling with this eclipse-cs shortcoming for years, and so far I am convinced that it truly isn't possible. You'd have to add this feature to the eclipse-cs code yourself, so it seems.

Sorry for the bleak outlook. "Cannot do" isn't really what you want for an answer, but it may still save some people who google for a solution some time.

Comment: I have exactly this problem; +1 for saving me some time.  But given that there is no "reload" or "refresh" from within Eclipse, how are people causing Eclipse to see any changes?  Will closing and reopening Eclipse cause the xml to reload?  (Yes, I've been trying that; I can't tell if it's working or not, since I'm trying to test if the XML is configured properly, and not seeing an effect could mean the Eclipse code is stale, could mean the XML is still faulty)

Comment: Right, just press *File --> Restart* in Eclipse. A faulty XML should cause errors in the Eclipse *Error Log*.

Comment: **Update:** I just tried it on Eclipse Kepler (4.3) with Eclipse-CS 5.6, and it seemed to pick up changes to the XML automatically (including suppression.xml).

Comment: @Thomas - I'm using exactly that setup, but I don't see it picking up configuration changes to either file. How long does it take to reload, and does it rerun the checks automatically after it does?

Comment: @DavidHarkness It only runs when the projects are built (there is a "Checkstyle builder"). So normally it won't run automatically. But I'd still be happy if at least I wouldn't have to restart Eclipse all the time ... The 4.3/5.6 setup at work doesn't pick up the changes, but the same at home does ... now what the heck is the difference!?

Comment: @Thomas - Same here: at home (Windows 7) it picks up changes when I select Checkstyle > Check Code with Checkstyle, but at work (Ubuntu 13.04) I have to restart Eclipse. I am running STS 3.3.0 in both places.

Comment: As I found today, **there is a Refresh button** for eclipse-cs: The Checkstyle preferences page contains it. See here for details and a screenshot: http://rolf-engelhard.de/2012/11/clearing-checkstyles-cache-in-eclipse/

Comment: @ChristianSemrau That is truly amazing. I can't *believe* I missed this all this time! You solved one of the great problems of our time. :-) Thanks! Might want to post this as an answer, too.

Comment: For comparison: I'm running Eclipse 4.3 with eclipse-cs 5.6 on Win8, and CS does not pick up the changes automatically. Resorted to restarting Eclipse before I stumbled upon the solution for manual refreshing.

Answer (score 20):

The **Checkstyle Preferences page** contains in the top right corner a small **refresh button**. Hit the button after you modified your checkstyle.xml or suppressions.xml and the new configuration will be used.

[image: The Checkstyle Preferences Refresh button]
<sub>(source: [rolf-engelhard.de](http://rolf-engelhard.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/checkstyle-refresh-cache.jpg))</sub>

Reference: http://rolf-engelhard.de/2012/11/clearing-checkstyles-cache-in-eclipse

Comment: Many readers get here looking for *"restart (or reload the config of) Eclipse-CS*", so it's nice if they, too, find an answer.

Comment: If the button does manually what you want to achieve from code, you could research how to trigger the same refresh behaviour as that button?

Comment: I know it is not direct answer to this question, but +1 for sorting out how to refresh the previously loaded, and later modified checkstyle.xml file